# How to run the .NET portability analyzer for a web site application

Tags: .net, portability

The .NET Portability analyzer is asking for a DLL or EXE in order to run.
How can I run it on a Web Site (Web App) project?

Thanks,
Niv.

Answer (score 0):

According to the readme (https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-apiport/blob/master/docs/VSExtension/README.md) you can run it against a solution or project in Visual Studio, so as long as your website has a solution file associated with it, you should be able to use it. It gives the following instructions:

> Open a project or solution in Visual Studio
>
> Open Solution Explorer
>
> Right-click on the project or solution you want to analyze
>
> Select "Analyze Assembly Portability"

Comment: The option of "Analyze Assembly Portability" is available only in some types of projects (like Class library or Console Application) but i don't see this option in Web Site type of project.

Comment: ok. well, admittedly I didn't try it. But in that case the readme is a little bit inaccurate.

Comment: Web sites produce a DLL; you can just run it against the DLL generated by that project